# Angular model is null inside resource promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I am trying actualize an angular model inside a resource promise, but the problem is that this model is undefined.

Basically I have list of products that are showing on the page and for all products I have a delete action. I want, after successfully deleting the product, to actualize the list of products on the page.

My resource definition:

```
angular.module('bookshop').factory('productsFactory', function($resource, serverUrlValue) {
  return $resource(serverUrlValue + '/bookshop/products/:id', {
    id: '@id',
    query: '@query'
  }, {
    update: {method: 'PUT'},
    search: {method: 'GET', params: '@query', url: serverUrlValue + '/bookshop/products/search', isArray: true}
  });
});
```

My controller definition:

```
angular.module('bookshop').controller('cmsProductsController', function($state, $stateParams, utilService, productsFactory, categoriesFactory) {
  this.products = productsFactory.query();
  //skipped methods
  this.remove = function(productId) {
    //here object looks good
    console.log(this.products);
    this.result = productsFactory.delete({id: productId}).$promise.then(function() {
        //here object is undefined
        console.log(this.products);
        this.products = productsFactory.query();
    })
  }
});
```

My HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in cmsProductsCtrl.products track by $index">
  <td>{{product.name}}</td>
  <td>{{product.price | currency}}</td>
  <td>
    <a ng-click="cmsProductsCtrl.remove(product.id)" href="">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash icon-sm"></span>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Also for managing controllers and views I am using ui-router.

My route definition:

```
angular.module('bookshop').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('cms.products', {
    url: '/products',
    controller: 'cmsProductsController',
    controllerAs: 'cmsProductsCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'core/cms/products/cms-products.tpl.html'
  });
});
```

Screen from debugger:

[image: Screenshot of the console in developer tools, showing a collapsed Resource object with a $promise and $resolved proerty. Underneath is the string undefined, printed from the above code]

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the @Jesus Carrasco I solved my problem, by these changes in controller

Solution:

```
angular.module('bookshop').controller('cmsProductsController', function($state, $stateParams, utilService, productsFactory, categoriesFactory) {
  this.products = productsFactory.query();
  //skipped methods
  this.remove = function(productId) {
    var model = this;
    //object looks good
    console.log(model.products);
    productsFactory.delete({id: productId}).$promise.then(function() {
      //object also looks good
      console.log(model.products);
      model.products = productsFactory.query();
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: check this.products. because you are inside a function so. this. is on the function ambit. so instead of thad try use  var vm = this; and vm.products

Comment: You haven't created a delete method on the `resource` it seems...

Comment: No in resource by default is creating delete method [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is the ambit of `this`, its better using $scope or even better the alias like vmSomething = this; to avoid this kind of problems. Try this example.

**State Config Phase**

```
$stateProvider.
state('yourstate',{
 url:'yoururl',
 controller:'cmsProductsController',
 controllerAs:'vm',
 templateUrl:'yourhtmlroute'
});
```

**Controller**
    Avoid using this. try better use of controllerAs

```
angular.module('bookshop').controller('cmsProductsController', 
function($state, $stateParams, utilService, productsFactory, 
categoriesFactory) {
  //skipped methods
  var vm = this;
  vm.remove = function(productId) {
//here object looks good
console.log(vm.products);
    vm.result = productsFactory.delete({id: productId}).$promise.then(function() {
    //here object is undefined
    console.log(vm.products);
    vm.products = productsFactory.query();
    })
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in vm.products track by $index">
  <td>{{product.name}}</td>
  <td>{{product.price | currency}}</td>
  <td>
    <a ng-click="vm.remove(product.id)" href="">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash icon-sm"></span>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

if you ar using ui-router in state use controllerAs:'vm' if not in your ng-controller add 'controllerName as vm'

Comment: Sorry I forgot add ui-router definition in my question, now it is up to date

Comment: have you try my example?,, or if you can prived a fiddle or plunkr. can help